# How does vim and vscode force write to file used by another process?

Tags: windows, vim, visual-studio-code, filesystems, ioexception

On Windows, I have a file that is being used by a Java process. When I try to delete the file or write to it with notepad, I get the standard failure due to file used by another process. But I am able to write to the file with vim and vscode. How is this possible? Does vim and vscode use some dark magic powerful API?

Comment: Windows filesystems use cooperative sharing for read/execute, write/append, and delete/rename access. Most language runtimes implicitly share read/execute and write/append access. This allows opening the file again (regardless of process; this has nothing to do with processes) with write/append access, which can be used to truncate and rewrite the file. It does not allow opening the file again with delete/rename access. IIRC Notepad removes the previous file and creates a new file. vim probably truncates and rewrites the file contents.

Comment: Thanks Eryk! In C#, I can confirm 'truncate and rewrite' with `FileStream` works while `File.WriteAllText()` throws IOException.